# Calculating adjusted p-values in Python

Tags: python, statistics, p-value, q-value

So, I've been spending some time looking for a way to get adjusted p-values (aka corrected p-values, q-values, FDR) in Python, but I haven't really found anything. There's the `R` function `p.adjust`, but I would like to stick to Python coding, if possible. Is there anything similar for Python?

If this is somehow a *bad question*, sorry in advance! I did search for answers first, but found none (except a Matlab version)... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is available in statsmodels.

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/stats.html#multiple-tests-and-multiple-comparison-procedures

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.multipletests.html

and some explanations, examples and Monte Carlo
http://jpktd.blogspot.com/2013/04/multiple-testing-p-value-corrections-in.html

Comment: In statsmodels 0.80, use `import statsmodels.stats.multitest as multi; multi.multipletests(...)`.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [biostathandbook](http://www.biostathandbook.com/multiplecomparisons.html), the BH is easy to compute.

```
def fdr(p_vals):

    from scipy.stats import rankdata
    ranked_p_values = rankdata(p_vals)
    fdr = p_vals * len(p_vals) / ranked_p_values
    fdr[fdr > 1] = 1

    return fdr
```

Comment: It's resulting in a different adjusted p-values array than `statsmodels.stats.multitest.multipletests` with the method `fdr_bh`

Comment: Only minimally. I can give their version too and explain why on monday

Comment: It would be very helpful! Thank you

Comment: I am deliviering my PhD today so I am busy, but this answer does the final (IMO unnecessary step): https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532498/992687

Comment: No problem! Thank you very much for the link and good luck with the PhD!

Answer (score 5):

We also added FDR in SciPy (will be in the next release, SciPy 1.11).

https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.false_discovery_control.html

```py
from scipy import stats

ps = [0.0001, 0.0004, 0.0019, 0.0095, 0.0201, 0.0278, 0.0298, 0.0344,
      0.0459, 0.3240, 0.4262, 0.5719, 0.6528, 0.7590, 1.000]
stats.false_discovery_control(ps)

# array([0.0015    , 0.003     , 0.0095    , 0.035625  , 0.0603    ,
#        0.06385714, 0.06385714, 0.0645    , 0.0765    , 0.486     ,
#        0.58118182, 0.714875  , 0.75323077, 0.81321429, 1.        ])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the module `rpy2` that allows you to import R functions (b.t.w., a basic search returns [How to implement R's p.adjust in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450957/how-to-implement-rs-p-adjust-in-python)).

Another possibility is to look at the maths an redo it yourself, because it is still relatively easy.

Apparently there is an ongoing implementation in `statsmodels`: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/ipdirective/_modules/scikits/statsmodels/sandbox/stats/multicomp.html . Maybe it is already usable.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your question q-values and no answer provided a link which addresses this. I believe this package (at least it seems so from the documentation) calculates q-values in python

https://puolival.github.io/multipy/

and also this one

https://github.com/nfusi/qvalue