# How to calculate and add an FDR column to file in python

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, rpy2, fdr

I have the following input file (Input.xls):

```
Mouse   No_neigh_mouse  Human   No_neigh_hum    Intersection    TotalGeneTested
Gm20645 1   lnc3    2   1   8
Gm20645 1   lnc2    1   0   8
Gm20645 1   lnc1    2   1   8
Gm26549 2   lnc3    2   1   8
Gm26549 2   lnc2    1   1   8
Gm26549 2   lnc1    2   1   8
```

I would like to:

1. Calculate the hypergeom p-value for each row (done successfully)
2. Then calculate the fdr (which is same as BH) for p-value corrections
3. Add the adjusted p-value as the last column.

My expected output file will have four columns. First is the value of "Mouse", second is the value of "Human", third is "Hypergeom-pvalue", fourth is the "Adjusted-pvalue". I am able to generate the first 3 columns using the following code:

```
output=open("Hypergeom.xls", "w")
output.write("Mouse\tHuman\tHypergeom-pvalue\tAdjusted-pvalue\n")
Input = pd.read_table("Input.xls", sep="\t")

for i in range (0, len(Input.index)):
    hyperg= scipy.stats.hypergeom.sf(Input.ix[i,4], Input.ix[i,5], Input.ix[i,1], Input.ix[i,3],1) #calculates hypergeom p value without a problem
    newline = Input.ix[i,0], Input.ix[i,2], str(hyper)
    output.write('\t'.join(newline)+'\n')
    output.close()
```

Till here, the scripts works fine and I get the following output file ("Hypergeom.xls"):

```
Mouse   Human   Hypergeom-pvalue    Adjusted-pvalue
Gm20645 lnc3    0.25
Gm20645 lnc2    1
Gm20645 lnc1    0.25
Gm26549 lnc3    0.464285714
Gm26549 lnc2    0.25
Gm26549 lnc1    0.464285714
```

I then aimed at reopening the output file as an input and then calculate the fdr based on a command suggested by one of the users which utilizes R: [How to implement R's p.adjust in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450957/how-to-implement-rs-p-adjust-in-python)

My code then:

```
import rpy2.robjects as R
pvaluefile = pd.read_table("Hypergeom.xls", sep="\t")
pvalue_list = pvaluefile.ix[:,2].tolist()  #converts the value column series to a list
#Now, i try to apply the command from the SO link above
p_adjusted = R['p.adjust'](R.FloatVector(pvalue_list),method='BH')
for v in p_adjusted:
    print v
```

I get an error at the step p_adjusted = R [...]. Error is:
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Hence, I have two problems:

1. I cant figure out how to calculate the fdr by overcoming this
   error
2. How can i add the fdr column at the end of the file as a fourth column?

Comment: In the future, please tag a question like this with `rpy2`. It's somewhat annoying to read it through just to realize that at the bottom.

Comment: thanks- will make sure i do next time.

Comment: I was able to fix one part of the problem which is calculating fdr. I used the following commands: from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
 from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FloatVector
 stats = importr('stats')
 p_adjust = stats.p_adjust(FloatVector(pvalue_list), method = 'fdr')
 for v in p_adjust:
  print v                        However, i still cant figure how to add the fdr value at the last (4th) column