# AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.sandbox' has no attribute 'stats'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statsmodels, rpy2

Statsmodels seems to be the only library for python (besides `rpy2`) that provides an [FDR-based BH adjustment for p-values](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.fdrcorrection0.html#statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.fdrcorrection0), but it appears to not be included anymore:

```
statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.fdrcorrection0()

AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.sandbox' has no attribute 'stats'
```

Was this module removed from 0.6.1?  [Besides using rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450957/how-to-implement-rs-p-adjust-in-python), is there any other widely used implementation of FDR p-value adjustment?

Comment: I don't think the whole `stats` module has been removed. You probably need to import it explicitly. (Besides, `fdrcorrection0` is still in the [master branch](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/sandbox/stats/multicomp.py#L94))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still there in version 0.8.0:

```
import statsmodels
print(statsmodels.__version__)  
# 0.8.0rc1

from statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp import fdrcorrection0
print(fdrcorrection0)
# <function fdrcorrection at 0x0E5A3E88>
```

You probably did not import the submodules `stats` and `multipcomp`.

Comment: importing it directly worked.  Why is it when I tab-completed `statsmodels.sandbox.` I didn't see it in the list of suggested subpackages?

Comment: Yep. The module needs to be imported so introspection can see its content.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant code has been moved out of the sandbox and is now at `statsmodels.stats.multitest`
The sandbox function are just alias for the non-sandbox functions. The online documentation is currently a bit outdated.

The direct import

```
>>> from statsmodels.stats.multitest import fdrcorrection
>>> fdrcorrection
<function fdrcorrection at 0x0000000008554B70>
```

using it through the api

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> sm.stats.fdrcorrection
<function fdrcorrection at 0x0000000008554B70>
```

this is the old location which currently still contains an alias

```
>>> from statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp import fdrcorrection0
>>> fdrcorrection0
<function fdrcorrection at 0x0000000008554B70>
```

edited list of functions in `statsmodels.stats.multitest`:

```
>>> import statsmodels.stats.multitest as multi
>>> dir(multi) # output edited
['NullDistribution', 'fdrcorrection', 'fdrcorrection_twostage', 'local_fdr', 'multipletests']
```