# How to calculate pearsonr (and correlation significance) with pandas groupby?

Tags: pandas, group-by, scipy, correlation, pearson-correlation

I would like to do a groupby correlation using pandas and pearsonr.

Currently I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df.groupby(['A','B'])[['C','D']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1]
```

However I would like to calculate the correlation significance using pearsonr (scipy package) like this:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
corr,pval= pearsonr(df['C'],df['D'])
```

How do I combine the groupby with the pearsonr, something like this:

```
corr,val=df.groupby(['A','B']).agg(pearsonr(['C','D']))
```

Comment: Mind adding samplle input and output ?

Comment: @srinath, sure, I have added some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you need to perform the Pearson's test between `C` and `D` for any combination of `A` and `B`.

To carry out this task you need to `groupby(['A','B'])` as you already done. Now your grouped dataframe is a "set" of dataframes (one dataframe for each `A,B` combination), so you can apply the `stats.pearsonr` to any of these dataframes through the `apply` method. In order to have two distinct columns for the test-statistic (r, correlation index) and for the p-value, you can also include the output from `pearsonr` in a `pd.Series`.

```
from scipy import stats

df.groupby(['A','B']).apply(lambda d:pd.Series(stats.pearsonr(d.C, d.D), index=["corr", "pval"]))
```

The output is:

```
         corr      pval
A B                    
0 0 -0.318048  0.404239
  1  0.750380  0.007804
  2 -0.536679  0.109723
  3 -0.160420  0.567917
  4 -0.479591  0.229140
..        ...       ...
9 5  0.218743  0.602752
  6 -0.114155  0.662654
  7  0.053370  0.883586
  8 -0.436360  0.091069
  9 -0.047767  0.882804

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

In jupyter:

[image]

Another advice I can give you is to adjust the p-values to avoid false-positives, since you are replicating the experiment several times:

```
corr_df["qval"] = p_adjust_bh(corr_df.pval)
```

I used the `p_adjust_bh` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450957/how-to-implement-rs-p-adjust-in-python) (answer from @Eric Talevich)